# Combining OpenMP and OpenCL

Tags: opencl, openmp, reduction

My task is to compute the sum on an array.

What I plan to do is to perform a partial sun using OpenCL so that the kernel returns a smaller array of the size corresponding to the number of work-items.
And then to use OpenMP to sum up this somewhat little array.

Now, I'm wondering if I can use OpenMP in the host part of my OpenCL code. If yes, can I use OpenCL type (say cl_float4) with OpenMP.

I thank you in advance,

```
     Éric.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cl_float4` basicly represents an array of 4 `float` values with proper memory alignement for GPUs. However, it can be used in host code without any problems.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use OpenMP in your host code, and yes, you could use cl_float4 inside an OpenMP block. OpenMP doesn't much care what you do inside a parallel section.